# Change the quotations as if in Microsoft Word

Tags: code-golf, string

I noticed that in Microsoft Word, single quotations are either `‘` or `’`, but not in Notepad. Your task today is: given a string `q`, convert all the `'` characters (only) to `‘` or `’`, according to these rules, and then output it:

- If the character before the quote is a space, and after it comes a character, it becomes `‘`
- If the character before the quote is a letter, and after it is a space, it becomes `’`
- If the character before and after the quote is a letter, it becomes `’`
- If the character before and after the quote is a space, it becomes `‘`
- If the quote comes at the beginning it will be `‘`, if it comes at the end it becomes `’`
- If consecutive quotes come one after another, the first 2 become `‘’` and remaining ones become `’`

### Test Cases

```
'Hello'= ‘Hello’ (rules 1 and 2)
'=‘              (rule 5)
H'h=H’h          (rule 3)
 ' = ‘           (rule 4)
'' = ‘’          (rule 6)
a'''b=a‘’’b      (overriding by rule 6)
```

I'm keeping it this because although it is confusing, it is what the output should be, so if I had to make it more clearer, it will come at the expense of understanding it.

You can assume `q` contains only upper and lowercase letters, spaces, and quotation marks.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

**EDIT**: Although in MS Word rule 6 does **not** override all the other rules, since answers have already been posted that assume this case, I will keep it this way

Comment: Regarding rule #1 "space, and after it comes a character", should it say "after it comes a letter"?

Comment: Will rule 6 always override the previous ones? For example, for input `a''b`, what is expected output?

Comment: @OskarSkog I believe it means non-whitespace. Otherwise, it would be confuse what should `O'_'O` become, since `_` is neither a space nor a letter.

Comment: @tsh non-whitespace and non-quotemark

Comment: If input contains only a `'`, should it become `‘` or `’`?

Comment: @tsh See the second test case :) (So the answer is `‘`.)

Comment: Responding to all of these: 
1. It means the same thing
2. Since answers assume this case before I could modify it, yes
3. Kevin answered already

Comment: I dont think "Answers have to be full programs" is popular... A lot of languages have a bunch of boilerplate for full programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
(?<=^| )'|\b'(?=')
‘
'
’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX8PexjauRkFTvSYmSV3D3lZdk@tRwwwudSA58/9/dY/UnJx8dSDXQz2DS0FdgUtdXQEA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
(?<=^| )'|\b'(?=')
‘
```

Quotes become "smart open" quotes at the beginning of the string (by rule 5), after a space (by rules 1, 4 and 6), or after a letter and before a quote (by rule 6).

```
'
’
```

All other quotes become "smart close" quotes.

I tried coding the reverse logic by handling "smart close" quotes first but the best I could do was 29 bytes:

```
(?<=')'|\b'(?!')|'$
’
'
‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX8PexlZdU70mJkldw15RXbNGXYXrUcNMLnUgOeP/f3WP1JycfHUg10M9g0tBXYFLXV0BAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Quotes become "smart close" quotes after quotes (by rule 6), after a letter but not before a quote (by rules 2 and 3), or at the end (by rule 5).

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 42 bytes

```
'('+)
‘$.1*’
(^| )'
$1‘
'($|\w)
’$1
```

Assumes rule 6 takes prio over the other rules.

I have the feeling the first step can be shorter (perhaps with a `+^` loop), but couldn't really find anything yet..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9dQ11bk@tRwwwVPUOtRw0zuTTiahQ01blUDIFiXOoaKjUx5SD5mSqG//@re6Tm5OSrc6lzeahncCkAGepcJanFJepgAGIBAA) or [try it online with `<`/`>`](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9dQ11bk8tGRc9Qy45LI65GQVOdS8XQhktdQ6UmplyTy07F8P9/dY/UnJx8dS51Lg/1DC4FIEOdqyS1uEQdAkBMAA) instead of `‘`/`’` so it's a bit more distinguishable).

**Explanation:**

Replace any sequence of two or more quotes with one opening quote and the rest closing quotes:

```
'('+)
‘$.1*’
```

Replace a quote at the start of the string, or a quote with a space before it, with the opening quote:

```
(^| )'
$1‘
```

Replace a quote at the end of the string, or a quote with a after it, with the closing quote:

```
'($|\w)
’$1
```

Comment: Seems like a reasonable assumption

Comment: Line 5 looks wrong IMHO.

Comment: @Neil You're completely right, it was wrong! Should be fixed now (although the output remains the same, so the test cases aren't exactly well-covering imo).

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 109 bytes

```
:z;s/'''/''’/g;t z;
s/''/‘’/g
s/ '(.)/ ‘\1/g
s/([a-zA-Z])'([a-zA-Z ])/\1’\2/g
s/^'/‘/g
s/'$/’/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/36rKulhfXV0diB81zNRPty5RqLLmAgnpP2qYARYC8hTUNfQ09RWAIjGGYAGN6ETdKkfdqFhNdRhTIVZTP8YQqCPGCKwkDmwCmKmuog826f9/dY/UnJx8dS51Lg/1DC4FdQUudXWFf/kFJZn5ecX/dV0B)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 75 bytes

```c
x,o;f(*s){for(x=o=0;*s=*s-39?s[x=0]:8216+x|o&!s[x=1]|o>64&s[1]>64;o=*s++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RToMwFIav6VMcMa6lMMPULNPKjPFmF7wBEsMqHU0qXSjLMBuvLms3Fq/OOf//n349fMpVUW@GoYs0E4Sa4CB0Q7pEJzGjJqFm@vj8ZrIuifOXxcNsHnZHPblxwiw/6uX8aWKyWW4r0zYchgHrh1tZc7X7LuFVaV6o8r5aon9tz6uicRL6KWRNAnRAninbSxRI@vH1nqYR@H7AkCfrlkJbmjbLIQGb9FIfr0qlNPajyzTWFa7GDjBcvatZYIzXfgQx9AydX4X1TmSLOLcMezAQB6IgLcTRGFDJQNpzkOege2749pfYncg67mOecNO52zZ2WRD/TpnP2kJGvUf98MeFKjZmOAE)

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 70 bytes

```
(strse x "'""’""’(’+)"(conc "‘" (m 1))" ’"" ‘""^’""‘")
```

Not sure how many bytes this is because Unicode but Steffan kindly counted them and here's the algo:

1. Replace all ' with ’.
2. Do "rule six" specially
3. Replace `^’` and  `’` with opens

Comment: Looks like this is 70 bytes ([here's a counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)). Maybe you could save some by storing the special characters in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

## Sed

Here's a shorter version of matteo_c's answer:

```
:z;s/'''/''’/g;t z;
s/''/‘’/g
s/'/’/g
s/^’/‘/g
s/ ’/ ‘/g
```

Comment: This is 72 bytes, btw